# How to get values inside (...) and take mean?

Tags: r, mean, median, confidence-interval, ellipsis

I am using package `R0`. I am trying to replicate the example provided in CRAN pdf but not getting exactly same result as provided in pdf.

code:

```
library(R0)
data(Germany.1918)
mGT <- generation.time("gamma", c(3,1.5))
SB <- est.R0.SB(Germany.1918, mGT)
##Results will include "most likely R(t)" (ie. the R(t) value for which the computed probability
##is the highest), along with 95% CI, in a data.frame object
SB
# Reproduction number estimate using Real Time Bayesian method.
# 0 0 2.02 0.71 1.17 1.7 1.36 1.53 1.28 1.43 ...
SB$Rt.quant
# Date R.t. CI.lower. CI.upper.
# 1 1918-09-29 0.00 0.01 1.44
# 2 1918-09-30 0.00 0.01 1.42
# 3 1918-10-01 2.02 0.97 2.88
# 4 1918-10-02 0.71 0.07 1.51
# 5 1918-10-03 1.17 0.40 1.84
# 6 1918-10-04 1.70 1.09 2.24
# 7 1918-10-05 1.36 0.84 1.83
# 8 1918-10-06 1.53 1.08 1.94
# 9 1918-10-07 1.28 0.88 1.66
# 10 1918-10-08 1.43 1.08 1.77
# ...
```

I have three queries.

1. The last command `SB$Rt.quant` shows NULL in output. How can I get exactly the same result as in the example?
2. How can I get values hidden in (...) for both command: `SB` and `SB$Rt.quant`?
3. How can I take mean and median of SB and get confidence interval of related mean and median of SB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments have been changed now. You have to use `SB$conf.int` to get the confidence interval like

```
library(R0)
## Data is taken from the paper by Nishiura for key transmission parameters of an institutional
## outbreak during 1918 influenza pandemic in Germany)
data(Germany.1918)
mGT <- generation.time("gamma", c(3,1.5))
SB <- est.R0.SB(Germany.1918, mGT)
SB
SB$conf.int
```

Then you can use `write.csv(SB$conf.int)` to print all the values. If you want to have both R and confidence interval as like the example in the `R0` pdf document you can use the following code

```
cbind(Rt=SB$R, SB$conf.int)
```

Reading 3rd question, I think you can get the mean by using
`SB$R` and the median function is not available in the package. The confidence interval is already available through `SB$conf.int`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Bappa Das. SB$cont.int shows me confidence interval but does not match with the result provided in example. Also it does not show associated Rt. How can I get that?

Comment: SB$R answered my second question. Thanks a lot.